# Englische Eigennamen ohne Bindestrich?

Tags: english-to-german, standard-german, english

Der Duden gibt für die Schreibweise von englischen Begriffen die Bindestrichregel aus, Verbindungen aus zwei Substantiven zusammen zu schreiben, oder aber mit Bindestrich. Beispiele: Braintrust, Bottleparty, Economy-Class, Pole-Position, Desktoppublishing, Desktop-Publishing (beides richtig) etc.

Was gilt für drei Substantive, z. B. "Message Passing Interface"?

Warum ist für den Duden "Customer-Relationship-Management" mit Bindestrich, "Instant Messaging" aber ohne Bindestrich richtig (weder Bindestrich noch zusammengeschrieben)?

Comment: Hast du eine Antwort auch folgende Fragen: Was gilt für drei Substantive, z. B. "Message Passing Interface"? 
Warum ist für den Dud. "Customer-Relationship-Management" mit Bindestrich, "Instant Messaging" aber ohne Bindestrich richtig (weder Bindestrich noch zusammengeschrieben)?

Comment: Hier noch ein Link, der diesbezügliche Grammatikregeln beschreibt (liest sich das nicht irgendwie wie mein kleines Mathebeispiel?) https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/Schreibung-von-Fremdwortern-aus-dem-Englischen

Comment: *Instant* ist hier ein Adjektiv. Wenn Du Dich auf eine konkrete Frage beschränkst, hast Du deutlich bessere Chancen auf Antworten. Die Frage könnte auch wieder geöffnet werden, wenn Du sie in eine passende Form bringst.

Comment: @CarstenS und alle anderen: ich habe mal das Drumrum gelöscht und hoffe, die Frage kann jetzt wieder geöffnet werden. Das Beispiel _Instant Messaging_ habe ich bewusst drin gelassen, da hier ein Verständnisproblem zu liegen scheint (wie CarstenS bemerkte). Das kann und sollte man in einer Antwort dann ansprechen (finde ich). Und an das Sechseck: So grundsätzlich mag diese Community Humor, er sollte vielleicht nur nicht die eigentliche Frage überlagern :)

Comment: Das Wort *Eigennamen* im Titel der Frage finde ich irreführend.

Answer (score 8):

Das Deutsch *kann* nicht nur zusammengesetzte Substantive bilden, sondern *muss* es auch (der Fall wie im Englischen, dass Substantive einfach hintereinander weg geschrieben werden können, kommt im Deutschen nicht vor)

> Zusammengesetzungen aus Substantiven werden entweder zusammengeschrieben oder durch Bindestrich gekoppelt.

Diese Regel gilt offensichtlich nicht nur für *zwei*, sondern für *beliebig viele* Substantive, die Zusammensetzungen bilden. Es muss also

> Message-Passing-Interface

oder (unübersichtlicher, daher schlechter)

> Messagepassinginterface

heißen.

Der Fall mit

> Instant Messaging

ist einfach zu erklären: Das ist keine Zusammensetzung aus zwei Substantiven (sondern aus einem Adjektiv und einem Substantiv), kann daher sowohl getrennt alls auch zusammen geschrieben werden.

> Hot Dog, Hotdog